# Second Click Not Recognized for Input Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, input

I'm building a program using flask and html. I have an input button in a form like so:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_button" name="my_button" value="Submit" onclick="loading()">
```

When I click the button the first time, my `loading()` function successfully triggers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loading(){
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = "[Loading]"
}
</script>
```

and changes the content of the `#loading` div to say "[Loading]". However, if I then click the button a second time, I get the following javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: loading is not a function
at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

The rest of the button's action executes (e.g. what's supposed to happen when I click "Submit") but the `onclick` function does not.

If I wait a while and then click the button, however, the `onclick` function fires again.

**Why does the `onclick` not fire when I click the button after having clicked it once unless I wait a minute or more?**

I've included the full code below for reference:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block page_content %}

<h1 style="display: inline; margin-right: 20px;">{{ title }}</h1>

<h2 id="loading">Placeholder</h2>

<div class="container button_row">

    <form id="form_main" action="/get/all" method="post">

        <input type="submit" id="submit_button" name="my_button" value="Submit" onclick="loading()">

    </form>

</div>

<h2 class="header_margin">{{display_type}}</h2>

{% for item in display %}

    <p><b>{{item}}</p>

{% endfor %}


<!-- Makes the loading div appear until the page refreshes -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loading(load_what){
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = "[Loading]"
    }
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

and css:

```
#loading {
    display: none; /* Start out hidden always */
    color: #007BFF;
}
```

Comment: Is your `<script>` tag code inside `div#loading`? If not, the issue could be somewhere else, could you please provide a bigger context so we can help you more accurately.

Comment: You are defining your loading() function with a delay somewhere. I bet if you just refresh the page and click on button within the same timeframe (first second) you will get the same issue. Submit button submits the form and reloads it and at the time your javascript function is not available yet.

Comment: I've updated my question to show my full code.